# If a linear function $f$ is discontinous at a certain point, show that $f$ is discontinuous at every point

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $E,F$ be normed vector spaces.  If a linear function $f: E \rightarrow F $ is discontinous at a certain point, show that that $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $E$.

My attempt:

Proving the contrapositive:

Assume that $f$ is continuous at $a\in E$. We prove that $f$ satisfies $||f(x)||\leq M||x||$ for every $x\in E$.  Take $\epsilon =1 $, so there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $||x-a||<\delta  \implies ||f(x)-f(a)||<1.$

Let If $x=0$, the inequality holds, since $f$ being linear implies $f(0)=0.$

Now let $x\neq 0$ and $0<1/c<\delta$. So $v=\dfrac{x+c||x||a}{c||x||}$ is such that $v-a$ has norm $1/c<\delta$. Therefore, for such a $v$ we have  $||f(v)-f(a)||<1.$ By linearity, it also follows that:

$$\bigg|\bigg|f\bigg(\dfrac{x+c||x||a}{c||x||}\bigg) -f(a)\bigg|\bigg| = \dfrac{||f(x)||}{c||x||}<1$$

$\implies ||f(x)||\leq M||x||$, where $M =c$.

Also by the closure of operations in $E$ and also by linearity of $f$ it is true that:

$||f(x)-f(y)||=||f(x-y)||\leq M ||x-y||$.

Therefore $f$ is lipschitz continuous and hence continuous for every $x\in E$.

Is this fine?

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{1}{\delta}<\delta$ when $\delta$ can be any positive real number?

Comment: That's true, gotta solve that!

Comment: @gcc-6.0 i think that i solved the problem.

Comment: I think the proof is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof looks fine now after correcting some errors. Showing the contrapositive is a good idea. This might be easier: Wlog we can assume $a=0$. Let us assume $f$ is continuous at $0$. This means $f(x_n) \to f(0)=0$ for every sequence $x_n \to 0$. Let $y\in E$ be arbitrary and pick a sequence $(y_n) \subset E$ with $y_n \to y$. Then $z_n:=y_n-y \to 0$ and hence we have $f(z_n)= f(y_n)-f(y)\to 0$, that is $f(y_n) \to f(y)$ and we are done.

So we have showed that for linear $f$ we have:
$$ f \ \text{continuous at 0} \Longleftrightarrow \ f \ \text{continuous (everywhere).}$$
You can further proof that these statements are equivalent to
$$ f \ \text{is bounded.}$$